# The C++ standard defines _Cpp17Destructible_ is there a trait I can use to check this?

Tags: c++, std

The C++ Standard defines *Cpp17Destructible* at [https://eel.is/c++draft/utility.arg.requirements#:Cpp17Destructible:~:text=%5Btab%3Acpp17.destructible%5D](https://eel.is/c++draft/utility.arg.requirements#:Cpp17Destructible:%7E:text=%5Btab%3Acpp17.destructible%5D)

Is there a trait I can use to check this in code?

`std::is_destructible` seems not to do the right thing as the following code compiles:

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_destructible_v<int>);

using f_ptr = int(*)(int);
static_assert(std::is_destructible_v<f_ptr>);

static_assert(std::is_destructible_v<int[4]>);
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::is_destructible` is almost the same in terms of syntactic requirement, except that it gives `true` for array and reference types, so

```
template<typename T>
struct is_cpp17destructible
: std::bool_constant<std::is_destructible_v<T> &&
                    !std::is_array_v<T> && !std::is_reference_v<T>> { };
```

will do as trait.

However, *Cpp17Destructible* also has a semantic requirement, namely that the destructor will not throw any exceptions. You can't test for that with a type trait. It is different from requiring that the destructor is `noexcept`, which could be checked with `std::is_nothrow_destructible` instead of `std::is_destructible`.